# How to sort array of dictionary in core data object?

Tags: swift

I want to sort below JSON based on two keys(compartmentNumber & row) and also tried code sample mentioned below its throughing an error.

```
{
    "response": {
        "flightLegId": "FL004",
        "loadable": [{
            "position": {
                "deckNumber": 1,
                "compartmentNumber": 1,
                "leftRight": "ALL",
                "row": 1
            },
            "uld": {
                "uldAirline": "KL",
                "uldNumber": "ULD007",
                "uldPrefix": "PAG",
                "commodity": [{
                    "commodityCode": "C",
                    "airportCode": "GLA",
                    "hasDangerousGoods": false,
                    "pieceCount": 0,
                    "weightKg": 710
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "position": {
                "deckNumber": 1,
                "compartmentNumber": 1,
                "leftRight": "ALL",
                "row": 2
            },
            "uld": {
                "uldAirline": "KL",
                "uldNumber": "ULD007",
                "uldPrefix": "PAP",
                "commodity": [{
                    "commodityCode": "C",
                    "airportCode": "GLA",
                    "hasDangerousGoods": false,
                    "pieceCount": 5,
                    "weightKg": 780
                }, {
                    "commodityCode": "M",
                    "airportCode": "GLA",
                    "hasDangerousGoods": false,
                    "pieceCount": 5,
                    "weightKg": 780
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

---

```
 func sortResults(items: [Loadable]) -> [Loadable] {
            var sortResults: [Loadable] = []
            if let sortedArray = (items as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [
                NSSortDescriptor(key: "compartmentNumber", ascending: true),
                NSSortDescriptor(key: "row", ascending: true),
                ]) as? [Loadable] {
                sortResults = sortedArray
            }
            return sortResults
        }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Where do you get it?

Comment: below is the error messsage
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Loadable 0x600000293920> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Loadable is not key value coding-compliant for the key "compartmentNumber".'

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
 func sortResults(items: [Loadable]) -> [Loadable] {
        var sortResults: [Loadable] = []
        if let sortedArray = (items as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "position.compartmentNumber", ascending: true),
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "position.row", ascending: true),
            ]) as? [Loadable] {
            sortResults = sortedArray
        }
        return sortResults
    }
```